# Event in Update panel is not fired after rebinding control after Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a Gridview together with some LinkButton inside of an Update Panel. The click events are fired correctly, the way I expect them to work. BUT: After adding an additional Header Row to the grid in code behind, I need to rebind the Grid after each postback. Since then the click causes a postback, but the method is not executed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewFollowUpMove" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" OnRowDataBound="FollowUp_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="FollowUpMove_OnDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Due date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_DueDate" runat="server" OnClick="ActivateDueDate" CssClass="NoDeco" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ISSUEID") %>'>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelDueDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DueDate","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %>' Width="60px" Class="line"/></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTBX_DueDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DueDate") %>' Font-Size="11px" visible="false" OnTextChanged="TextChanged_DueDate" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillFollowUp();
        }
        FillFollowUp();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the commands that create and customize the additional Header row to the OnRowCreated Event. As I read somewhere: When a postback occurs, the Gridview must be recreated on the server, and in this process ItemCreated is fired for each item, but ItemDataBound is not (since the control properties are pulled from ViewState).
So building these headers in DataBound is the wrong choice!